# How to update table A values from table B values?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table (Table A) from the db2 where columns(Date, Part#, tool#, power) need to be updated based from the Table B.

```
Table A
Date   part# tool# power
04/09   12    1     500
04/10   13    2     600
04/11   14    1     700

Table B 
Date   part# tool# power speed wheel
04/09   12    1    500    128    2
04/10   13    2    600    129    2
04/11   14    1    700    130    4
04/12   15    3    800    130    3
04/13   16    1    500    140    3
04/14   17    3    500    150    4
```

So the final result in Table A should be like below

```
Table A
Date  part# tool# power
04/09 12     1     500
04/10 13     2     600
04/11 14     1     700
04/12 15     3     800
04/13 16     1     500
04/14 17     3     500
```

How will i do it using db2 sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
insert into a (date, part#, tool#, power)
    select b.date, b.part#, b.tool#, b.power
    from b
    where not exists (select 1 from a where b.date = a.date);
```

Comment: What is select 1 for?

Comment: @JuliusBennSabeniano . . . `EXISTS` only cares if *rows* are returned, not the values in the row.  `1` is the easiest thing to type.

Comment: ``` insert into public.table a (date, part#, tool#, power)
    select b.date, b.part#, b.tool#, b.power
    from (query of table b) b
    where not exists (select 1 from a where b.date = a.date); commit; ```

Comment: What I am trying to do is, update my public table a (selected columns that I need) from schema table b.